# Angular Routing not working when creating an HttpModule object

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use angular routing to route to a new url when a button is clicked. I also need to use the module HttpClient to call some calls to the backend. However, whenever I create a HttpClient object, the routing doesn't work and it routes to a blank page with no url extension. When I delete the object, the routing works again. Anyone know how to overcome this? Here are some of my code snippets.

**agent-page-component.ts (I create a Agent Service in the constructor)**

```
import { Router} from "@angular/router";
import { Agent } from '../../models/agent.model'
import { AgentService } from '../../services/agent.service';

import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-agent-page',
    templateUrl: './agent-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./agent-page.component.css']
})
export class AgentPageComponent implements OnInit {
    agents: Agent[] = [];
    private agentSub: Subscription;

    constructor(private agentService: AgentService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.agentService.getAgents();
        this.agentSub = this.agentService.getAgentUpdateListener().subscribe((agents: Agent[]) => {
            this.agents = agents;
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.agentSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

**agent.service.ts (this is where I import an HttpClient)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AgentService {
    private agents: Agent[] = [];
    private agentsUpdated = new Subject<Agent[]>();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    getAgentUpdateListener() {
        return this.agentsUpdated.asObservable();
    }

    getAgents(){
        this.http.get<{message: string, agents: Agent[]}>('http://localhost:3000/agents/Breach').subscribe((agentList) => {
            this.agents = agentList.agents;
        })
    }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AgentPageComponent } from './components/agent-page/agent-page.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './components/home-page/home-page.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'agents', component: AgentPageComponent},
  {path: '', component: HomePageComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: The problem might be in your logic, as there is no relation between HTTP and router Module

Comment: @JohnPark can you upload your code in stackbliz, as there is no relation between HTTP and routing.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add my agent.service (which use the HTTP) here. I have updated it.

Comment: @JohnPark Do you get any error on console ? also check what's the response you are getting in your service and another question is why service variable is private?

Comment: @Adityatoke I do not get any errors at all. I can't get any response right now because when I click the button, it redirects me to an empty page for some reason.

Comment: @JohnPark can you upload your project on stackbliz as there no link between HTTP and routing its hard to find because of which error is occuring.

Comment: @Adityatoke I got it to work. I don't know what I changed, but it worked haha. thank you.

Comment: @JohnPark hehehe great